# Expressing that two points are coincident.

Tags: geometry

If two points A and B are the same point, is it fine to say that A = B, or is there another way of expressing that two points are coincident?

Comment: Any two points are congruent.

Comment: Why would you even ask?  $A=B$ means exactly that $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry, I meant to express that the two points are at the same spot, or that they cover each other.

Comment: In geometry a point is not the location of some spot or of some other thing. The points $are$ the things. And in all math, $A=B$ means $A$ and $B$ are the same thing.